# Centering <a> in <div>

Tags: html, css, centering

I am trying to get my `<a>` tags centered in `div#teacherpageoptions`. They are centered in Microsoft Expression Web, but not when I view the page in a browser. What am I doing wrong?

```css
#blackbar {
  background-color: chartreuse;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 57px;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body,
#teacherpage {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}
hr {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.center {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.button {
  display: block;
  width: 115px;
  height: 25px;
  background: chartreuse;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.button1 {
  display: block;
  width: 115px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #008dde;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
}
p {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.auto-style1 {
  /* Make username hang a little to the left. */
  margin-left: 53px;
}
#teacherpage {
  height: 327px;
  background-color: gray;
}
#teacherpageoptions {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: auto;
}
.auto-style2 {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}
.auto-style3 {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
a {
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 100%;
}
a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(3);
  -ms-transform: scale(3);
  transform: scale(3);
}
```

```html
<div id="blackbar" class="auto-style3">
  <a href="Login2.php" class="button" style="float:left; text-decoration: none;"> Logout  </a> 
  <p style=" float:right; height: 36px;" class="auto-style1">Username
    <?php session_start(); echo $name=$ _SESSION[ 'name'] ?>
  </p>
</div>
<hr>

<div id="teacherpageoptions">

  <div class="wrapper" style="height:100px "><a href="MakeQuestions.php" class="button1" style="text-decoration: none"> Make Questions </a> 
    <div class="center"></div>
    <a href="MakeExam.php" class="button1" style="text-decoration: none"> Make Exam </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Microsoft was never that good at *web*. Your `.button1` are position absolute, why?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan +1 for your comment "Microsoft was never that good at web" - made me smile :)

Comment: Because in Microsoft Expression it appeared in the middle so I thought that was the solution to my problem. It appears that was not the case, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `position: absolute;` from the `.button1` and add `margin: 0 auto;` instead.

```css
#blackbar {
  background-color: chartreuse;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 57px;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body,
#teacherpage {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}
hr {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.center {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.button {
  display: block;
  width: 115px;
  height: 25px;
  background: chartreuse;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.button1 {
  display: block;
  width: 115px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #008dde;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  /* position: absolute; */
  margin: 0 auto;
}
p {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.auto-style1 {
  /* Make username hang a little to the left. */
  margin-left: 53px;
}
#teacherpage {
  height: 327px;
  background-color: gray;
}
#teacherpageoptions {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: auto;
}
.auto-style2 {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}
.auto-style3 {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
a {
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 100%;
}
a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(3);
  -ms-transform: scale(3);
  transform: scale(3);
}
```

```html
<div id="blackbar" class="auto-style3">
  <a href="Login2.php" class="button" style="float:left; text-decoration: none;"> Logout  </a> 
  <p style=" float:right; height: 36px;" class="auto-style1">Username
    <?php session_start(); echo $name=$ _SESSION[ 'name'] ?>
  </p>
</div>
<hr>

<div id="teacherpageoptions">

  <div class="wrapper" style="height:100px "><a href="MakeQuestions.php" class="button1" style="text-decoration: none"> Make Questions </a> 
    <div class="center"></div>
    <a href="MakeExam.php" class="button1" style="text-decoration: none"> Make Exam </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the "position:absolute" and put "margin:0 auto" instead.
Let me know how it worked.